# How to Reference App_Plugins Folder in Another Assembly for Umbraco?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

What I'm trying to do is setup a good development process for developing our in-house Umbraco packages. Basically, I want to version the source code for packages in their own repositories by having all the related code in a single assembly, without having to control an entire Umbraco install for each package.

The only issue I'm having with this is the HTML and JavaScript files, since they need to exist in the App_Plugins folder of the Umbraco project, I'm not able to have them in their own assembly. Is there a way in Umbraco to configure in my local install to look at another assembly for these files?

I'm able to use the TreeController in another assembly by just referencing the assembly in my Umbraco project. I could create a build task in the csproj to copy these files over, but I want to avoid this if possible.

```cs
    [Tree("settings", "siteSettings", TreeTitle = "Site Settings", IsSingleNodeTree = true, TreeGroup = "settingsGroup", SortOrder = 10)]
    [PluginController("SiteSettings")]
    public class SiteSettingsTreeController : TreeController
    {
        protected override TreeNode CreateRootNode(FormDataCollection queryStrings)
        {
            var root = base.CreateRootNode(queryStrings);

            root.RoutePath = "settings/siteSettings/overview";

            root.Icon = "icon-wrench";

            root.HasChildren = false;

            root.MenuUrl = null;

            return root;
        }
...
```